Flex: 1 and Wrap not working inside grid?
I was trying to make container inside grid cell span to fill rest of space and let items inside wrap as needed but its expanding my table instead of behaving like it would behave outside the table. Any idea how to achieve it and why it happens?
Inside table:
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content auto;">
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
  <div>
  asdasd
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 1; background-color: blue; gap: 4px; padding: 4px; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

Outside table:
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
  <div>
  asdasd
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 1; background-color: blue; gap: 4px; padding: 4px; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div><div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 100px;">A</div>
  </div>
</div>

https://jsfiddle.net/hvp14u5b/7/

Now I have suspicion its because the column behavior setup (max-content, auto) maybe? I have some full rows made with "grid-column: 1 / -1;" that I would need that behavior overriden despite how the rest of table should behave tho.

The reason it's expanding your table is because table cells generally favor content fitting. This causes the table to expand to its surroundings instead of allowing the flexbox content to wrap.You can remedy this by setting your min-width:0 to force wrap the flex container and prevent the table from expanding. You could also try setting widths on grid cells to control their sizing.

I was trying to mess with min-width on several elements but I did never got it working properly. Can you provide working example?
